# Making a table tennis game

Tags: xna

I am very interested in making a table tennis game. It will be in 2D specially as I have no experience dealing the 3D. I have built aero-fighter in java. No i am learning XNA and want to **make a table tennis (ping pong) video game** in it. It will be human vs computer game.

I have some idea to do the task. But I am eager to know how the tennis game industry move their player ? 
There are several question about the game -- 
   ***What will be the best to create such a game in 2D or 3D ?

- How can i move the ball in 2D game? The equation of the ball move for top,under,flat shot or spin?
- How can i move my player?
- How can i spin the bat of player and the ball?***

  First of all my idea is , making a sprite sheet of some special move for such -
  Forehand counter hit, Backhand counter hit, Forehand push, Forehand serve, Backhand Serve... etc.
  But it seems to boring and time consuming a lot. What is the best idea to handle such things or this problem?
  I do not know the idea to movement of the tt ball. How can i use  the spin in the ball and how can i show the spin -- Is it with the sprite?

  Please help me if anyone know anything about it. I also like to have some links to get the concept of the video game....

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you get confident with 2D games before you start with 3D. 3D is much more complex and your unlikely to get anywhere if you try to run before you can walk.

The rest of your question is a little broad to answer properly, I suggest you go through the [tutorials on app hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/tutorial/2dgame/getting_started) and raise a new topic if you need help with a specific part.

Answer (score 0):

If you become familiar with a physics engine such as farseer (harder to initially learn, better in the long run) or Physics2D (easy to pickup, but a little limiting) you could create a pong clone in under an hour I would say.